# copy only the working directory (skipping .hg directory) in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have a huge mercurial repository and it takes a couple of hours to clone.
All that I need is a copy of working directory so that I can start to test things.

Is there a way to make a copy of only working directory (skipping the .hg directory which takes lot of time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If the repo you are cloning is local, you can just use a filesystem copy and exclude the `.hg` folder. For example, if you are on Windows:

  ```
  robocopy <repo> <repo-clone> /XD .hg
  ```
- If this clone is a repetitive task in your workflow you can clone once from the remote and then always do the initial clone to a new repo locally (local clones are much much faster.)
- If you have local access to the remote repo (e.g. RDP, etc.) you can use `hg archive` to create a zip file of a specific revision and then download that zip file:

  ```
  hg archive project-1.0.zip -r tag-1.0 -X ".hg*"
  ```